# Show element html if this child contains text

Tags: jquery, html

This is part of my html:

```
<div class="rigaEven">
                <div class="col1">
                    <p class="stage">ROOM B</p>
                    <p class="where">Street</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col2 half">
                    <p class="when">09:00 - 11:00</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col3">
                     <p class="what">EVENT</p>
                     <p class="type">event</p>
                     <p class="who">PIER LUIGI GAROTTI</p>
                </div>
            </div>
<div class="rigaOdd">
              <div class="col1">
                    <p class="stage">ROOM C</p>
                    <p class="where">Street</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col2 half">
                    <p class="when">09:00 - 11:00</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col3">
                     <p class="what">MEETING</p>
                     <p class="type">event</p>
                     <p class="who">FRANCESCA GUARINO</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I'd like to hide div with class rigaEven or rigaOdd if this child col3 contains a specific text.
I'd implement this method but not work:

```
function(filter){
    if($( \".col3:contains("+filter+")\" )){ 
        $(\".rigaEven\").show();
    }
    if($( \".col3:contains("+filter+")\" )){ 
        $(\".rigaOdd\").show();
    }
}
```

Comment: you escaped the wrong quotes `if($(".col3:contains(\"+filter+\")" )`

Comment: I try this with Android's WebView but doesn't work:https://pastebin.com/VpfcmPp7

Answer (score 0):

First of all your function has no name so you cannot call it anywhere:

```
function myFilter(filter){};
//or 
var myFilter = function(filter){};
```

Second, for your example(in your code the if condition is the same for both cases so it cannot work):

```
function myFilter(filter){
  //you need to check what value filter has
  if($(".col3:contains("+filter+")" ) && (filter === "john")){ 
    $(".rigaEven").show();
  } 
  if(!$( ".col3:contains("+filter+")" ) && (filter === "paul")){ 
    $(".rigaOdd").show();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I generate regExp from filter than match it with the text of my div?

Comment: Not really understand what you want but jQuery `contains()` needs  a string for parameter and as far as I know regexp `match()` produce an array so I guess eventually u can do  something like `".col3:contains("+filter[i]+")` in a loop

Comment: I found the solution:function myFilter(filter){
    $(".rigaEven:has(.what:contains("+filter+")" )).show();